# Counting ways to exchange gifts so that nobody gets their own gift

Tags: combinatorics

The following is the question I am trying to solve.

> There are six students each having a different gift. How many different ways can these students exchange gifts so that none of them get their own gift ?

I've tried with 1, 2 ,3 and 4 students to get 0,1,2 and 9 ways but I cannot see a pattern.
Can I have some help with the general case n ?

Comment: do you mean that each student has n gifts initially and at the end of the exchange?

Comment: I've actually figured it out. It was about derangements. Thank you though.